Create transparent image based on mask
I feel very stupid, but I can't find how to create an image where only the image inside the mask is kept while the rest of the image is transparent. I tried to plug the mask to "alpha" directly, or via a "alpha over", without chance: the background is half-transparent instead of fully transparent:

What am I doing wrong?
EDIT I found a solution by using directly alpha over with the image and the color set to transparent and it works… but still curious to understand why my solution fails.

